# Actionscript help: Generated TextField() not appearing?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, text, field

thanks for checking out my question. I've tried a bunch of different things but I can't see where my error is here.

```
function addHighScore() {
    //highscoreTable.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
    var highscoreTable: TextField = new TextField();
    highscoreSec[indx] = hsSeconds;
    highscoreTable.text = "CAN YOU SEE MEEEE???";
    highscoreMS[indx] = hsMilliSec;
    addChild(highscoreTable);
    highscoreTable.border = true;
    highscoreTable.x = (stage.width - highscoreTable.width) / 2;
    highscoreTable.y = (stage.height - highscoreTable.height) / 2;
    indx++;
}
```

I have also imported flash.text.TextField()

Comment: where is this code located? Remove the () from the import, you do not want to call the constructor, you just want to import the class. (that is probably not the cause of your problem)

Comment: Probably your text field is there, but with white text on white. Also check if `embedFonts` is false and your `myFormat` is set to use an embedded font.